# Flutter: speech_to_text fail to initialize with android emulator

Tags: flutter, speech-to-text

I try to implement speed_to_text example https://pub.dev/packages/speech_to_text with Pixel C API 31 emulator but it failed

seems to be speed_to_text never initialized

however it works when I run on chrome web

I have add permission in manifest, use the minimum API version 31: minSdkVersion 31,   targetSdkVersion 31 and compileSdkVersion 31 in build.gradle

I look in mobile emulator for microphone permission and seems to be OK

what else I should check?

Comment: have to read permission section for android https://pub.dev/packages/speech_to_text#android

Comment: I already add these permissions

Comment: when I run app with cold boot, I can switch on/off microphone (and mobile show microphone on with icons) but nothing is return in SpeechRecognitionResult when I speak